# How to use Selenium TouchActions with a RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mobile, selenium-chromedriver, touch

I wrote some Javascript code with the `touchstart` and `touchmove` event. I want to test it using Selenium. I just discovered the [TouchActions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/touch/TouchActions.html) class with the `move` method which appears to be exactly what I want.

My tests are run with a [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html):

```
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

The driver will be a `ChromeDriver` or eventually a `FirefoxDriver`, not an `AndroidDriver`.

When I try to initialize the actions with:

```
TouchActions builder = new TouchActions(remoteWebDriver);
```

I get a cast error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Does anybody know what I am supposed to do? Is there a capability I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to be able to do that, one needs to first add the mobile capability to the driver (see [Mobile Emulation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation)):

```java
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5"); // Choose a device available in your version of chromimum
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Then at the moment you need the touch actions, you need to "augment" the driver, to be able to cast it:

`TouchActions builder = new TouchActions(new Augmenter().augment(remoteWebDriver));`

Then from that builder you can do `builder.down(), move(), scroll(), up()...` whatever you need.

Comment: Does it support real mobile device also? and same capabilities can be mentioned for safari browser?